# Letsencrypt + nginx + autorenewal + Infrastructure as code?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ansible, lets-encrypt, ubuntu-18.04

Our infrastructure is managed by Ansible (including nginx site configuration - they are generated using templates).

Now we generate letsencrypt certificates by `certbot` command automatically each 3 months, but we have ~1 minute downtime (we have to stop nginx, to bind certbot to 80).

How Letsencrypt + nginx integration for autorenewal can be made? And what about wildcards?

I have found some solutions like [How to setup Let's Encrypt for Nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 (including IPv6, HTTP/2 and A+ SLL rating)](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/a26737699a7e70a7093d4dc115915de8) but they use `python-certbot-nginx` which modifies site configs (and they will be replaced by Ansible on next Ansible run, so HTTPS will be broken).

Comment: Configure your Nginx to deal specifically with the URLs used by Let's Encrypt and forward them to `certbot` running on another port. See this example for HAProxy: https://jkraemer.net/2017/01/lets-encrypt-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy-and-stable-keys

Comment: Look at https://tom.busby.ninja/letsecnrypt-nginx-reverse-proxy-no-downtime/ and do use the `webroot` mode, not the `standalone` one. You should never need then to stop Nginx nor to change its configuration file at each renewal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best option is to use DNS certbot plugin.

1. You don't need to bind the port.
2. You don't need to generate self-signed certificates for nginx for first launch before first letsencript certificate is created.
3. Wildcards.